# Contacts on my Mac out of sync with my iPhone

Tags: icloud, contacts.app

I have what appears to be a massive collection of randomness in the Contacts list on my Mac, even though iCloud Sync is turned on. My iPhone is a much different, and cleaner, list.

Is there a way to reset my Mac's contacts with the iCloud version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `System Preferences app → iCloud` and toggle the checkmark shown alongside Contacts.

When you uncheck Contacts, the contact list shown in the Contacts.app is emptied. Re-checking forces the Contacts.app to reload from iCloud.

[image]